# Initialize TestContext without using mstest

Tags: c#, mstest

I am building a WPF application to run our UIA tests so that our QA testers can run them as well. The TestContext is set when I run from the test explorer or from mstest but is null when running from my application. From what I have read mstest is doing something to initialize the TestContext on each of my test classes and I would like to mimic what it is doing. Here is my code so you can see what my test class looks like.

```
[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        Logger.StartTestCaseRun(TestContext.TestName);
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanup()
    {
        Logger.EndTestCaseRun(TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome);
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        //DO WORK
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I would need to do to create a instance of the `TestContext` for each of my tests so I can mimic mstest?